# jquery ajax post() request not sent with XHR header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest

The following is the javascript from my erb template. When the user submits the form, it should be hijacked by jquery, the data submitted via a $.post(), and return false should prevent the page from redirecting, and the form submitting in the traditional manner. But im still getting the redirect, and request.xhr? is returning false.

```
<% javascript_tag do %>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    action = $('.edit_profile').attr('action');

    $('.edit_profile').submit(function(){

      form_data = $('.edit_profile').serialize();

      $.post(action, function($('.edit_profile').serialize()){
        $.colorbox.close();
      });
      return false;
    })
  });
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there were a few problems with your script.

```
$(function(){
    $('.edit_profile').submit(function(){
        var form_data = $('.edit_profile').serialize();
        $.post(this.action, form_data, function(){
            $.colorbox.close();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josiah! To be specific it was this line:
    $.post(action, form_data, function(){
(passing the form_data outside of the function instead of inside, where i had it)